# How can I add the P5-property to a s.Vector object?

Tags: p5.js

I have two different variations of the

```
  let diff = nearby.boid.velocity
  console.log(diff.p5) //undefined
  diff =  p5.Vector.div(diff, nearby.d*nearby.d)
  steering.add(diff)
```

Second:

```
  let diff = p5.Vector.sub(this.position, nearby.boid.velocity);
  console.log(diff.p5) // an object with the p5-property
  console.log('')
  diff.div(nearby.d*nearby.d);
  steering.add(diff);
```

I want to normalize the code so I can put it in a function. In the first example, I can't use diff.div and in the second, I can't use p5.vector.div.  p5.vector.sub is adding a the p5 property, can I do that without subtraction somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little confused about what you're trying to do: why do you need the `p5` reference inside your function? Why can't you use `p5.Vector.div()` in your second example? Can you post a [small example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows what you're trying to do, and why it won't work?

Keep in mind that there are two versions of the functions: static and non-static. For example:

- `p5.Vector.div()` is static, takes two parameters, and returns a result without modifying the parameters.
- `myVectorInstance.div()` is non-static. It takes one parameter, and modifies `myVectorInstances` to it contains the result.

If you want to create a function that does not affect the parameters, then you probably want to use the static version.

If you're curious, you can look at the code for `p5.Vector` [here](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/master/src/math/p5.Vector.js). Looks like it uses the `p5` reference internally to convert between degrees and radians using the `p5.toRadians()` and `p5.fromRadians()` functions. I don't know why some instances of `p5.Vector` populate it and others do not, but it seem like an implementation detail that you aren't supposed to rely on.